# Prove a one sided inverse matrix $B_{m\times m}$ of $A_{m\times m}$ is two sided inverse.

Tags: linear-algebra, linear-transformations

I am trying to proof that if $A_{m\times m}$ has inverse $B_{m\times m}$ then  $A_{m\times m}B_{m\times m}=Id_{m\times m}\leftrightarrow B_{m\times m}A_{m\times m}=Id_{m\times m}$.

Proof:

Suppose $V,W$ are two finite dimensional vector spaces with bases $A=\{a_1,...,a_m\},B=\{b_1,...,b_m\}$ respectively, $\forall T\in \mathrm{Hom}_{\mathbb{F}}(V,W)$ , $A_{m\times m}$ is defined as $M_{A\rightarrow B}(T)$. Since $B_{m\times m}$ exists then by definition $M_{B\rightarrow A}(T^{-1})$ exists. Therefore we have:

$A_{m\times m}B_{m\times m}=M_{A\rightarrow B}(T)M_{B\rightarrow A}(T^{-1})=M_{B\rightarrow B}(T\circ T^{-1})=Id_{m\times m}=M_{A\rightarrow A}( T^{-1}\circ T)=M_{B\rightarrow A}(T^{-1})M_{A\rightarrow B}(T)=B_{m\times m}A_{m\times m}$

as required. Is there any logical problem with the last step?

Comment: There is a problem with the current proof.  You are implicitly assuming that  if $S,T$ are linear transformations such that $S\circ T=Id$, then $T\circ S = Id$, and your proof is extending that result to matrices.  However, actually proving the result for linear transforms requires work.

Comment: I see. Well if $S \circ T=Id$ and $Id$ is bijective then $S\circ T$ is bijective hence $S$ is surjective and $T$ is injective. But by nullity rank theorem That makes $S$ injective too since its kernel is zero and $T$ is surjective Hence both $S$ and $T$ are bijective and thus invertible therefore $S\circ T = Id \implies T \circ S = Id$, now is using the above proof ok?

Comment: @AspiringMat:  Well, you still need something like Emilio's answer to guarantee that the thing you multiply $S$ on the right to get $Id$ is the same as the thing you multiply on the left.

Comment: So you mean I can't use the fact that $T^{-1}=S$ here is that right?
What about $T\circ S \circ T = T$ then $(T\circ S - Id)\circ T=0$, but here T is bijective and hence surjective so it can take any value really so that forces $T\circ S - Id = 0$ or $T \circ S  = Id$ right?

Comment: @AspiringMat I mean that writing $T^{-1}$ is implicitly assuming that $T$ has a two sided inverse (which is not true for maps between vector spaces of different dimensions, or maps between infinite dimensional vector spaces).  What you wrote just now works assuming you know know that you can cancel $T$ when $T$ is a bijection.  I am writing up a solution that doesn't gloss over anything, hopefully it will help.  (However, $XY=0$ does not in general imply $X=0$ or $Y=0$ for linear transformations).

Comment: @Aaron perhaps I wasn't very clear, what I meant was, since $\mathrm{Im}(T)$ is all of $V$ Since T is surjective, and $T \circ S - Id$ works on the range of T and it is always equal to 0 then the linear transformation must be the zero linear transf, thats what I meant

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your proof is transferring the corresponding result from linear transformations to matrices (and your gap in logic was going from the assumption that $T$ had a right inverse to the conclusion that the right inverse was also a left inverse), and so we want to establish that result first.  If you already have that at your disposal, then all you need to do is cite the result for linear transforms.  If not, here is a proof.

**Theorem:** If $V,W$ are vector spaces of dimension $n$, and $S:V\to W$, $T:W\to V$ such that $S\circ T=\operatorname{Id}_W$, then $T\circ S=\operatorname{Id}_V$.

We will need a few ingredients for the proof.

First, by the rank-nullity theorem, combined with the observation that a linear transformation is injective if and only if it has zero kernel and surjective if and only if its rank is equal to the dimension of the image space, we have that a linear map between two spaces of dimension $n$ is injective if and only if it is surjective.

Second, a bijective map of sets has a two sided inverse (or both a left inverse and a right inverse, which by Emilio's argument, must be equal).

Now, if $S\circ T=\operatorname{Id}_W$, which is a bijection, then $S$ is a surjection and $T$ is an injection, but because $S$ and $T$ are maps between equal dimensional spaces, they are both bijections.  Because bijective set maps have unique inverses, this shows that $S$ and $T$ are actually inverses of each other, and so $T\circ S=\operatorname{Id}_V$ as desired.

---

Here is a different perspective, related to your comment that $T\circ S \circ T = T$.  In [category theory](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Category_theory), instead  of using the notion of injection and surjection, they take the cancelability properties of injective and surjective maps as their replacements.  In particular, if $f$ is injective, and $fg(x)=fh(x)$, then $g(x)=h(x)$, and since this holds for every $x$, this implies that $g=h$. We say that injective maps are left-cancelable, or "monomorphisms" (monic for short).  Similarly, if $f$ is surjective, then $gf=hf$ implies that $g=h$.  We say that surjective maps are right-cancelable, or "epimorphisms" (epic for short).  It is an instructive exercise to show that epic set maps are surjective and monic set maps are injective.

So assume that $ST=I$. Then $TST-T=0$, which we can factor as $(T\circ S-I)\circ T=0\circ T$, and we would like to be able to cancel the $T$'s on the right.  From the previous solution, we have that $S\circ T=I$ implies that $T$ is injective, rank-nullity has that $T$ is surjective, and since surjective maps are epic, we can cancel on the right to get $TS-I=0$ or $TS=I$.

This is essentially the proof you gave, except placed into a broader context.

Comment: As an aside, it is worth comparing our use of the rank-nullity theorem to the statement that an injective or surjective map from a finite set to itself is a bijection.

Comment: Thanks for the elaborated answer!

Comment: @AspiringMat You're welcome.  Actually, I kind of want to add another proof that is related to another one of your comments, which is related to a framework of describing mathematical systems called ("Category theory")[https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Category_theory].  So check back here later, and hopefully I will have edited my answer.

Answer (score 5):

if they are square matrices then $A$ and $B$ can be broken down into product of elementary matrices, i.e. $$A=E_1E_2...E_k$$
$$B=E_k^{-1}E_{k-1}^{-1}...E_1^{-1}$$
One can check $AB=BA=I$

Comment: "then A and B can be broken down into product of elementary matrices": not clear why.

Answer (score 2):

If:
$$
AB=I \quad \mbox{and} \quad CA=I
$$
than
$$
(CA)B=IB \Rightarrow C(AB)=B \Rightarrow CI=B \Rightarrow C=B 
$$

Comment: This shows that if $A$ *has* a left and right inverse, then these must be the same.  The hard part is showing that if $A$ has a left inverse, then it also has a right inverse.  (And this part requires finite dimensionality, because there are counterexamples in infinite dimensions.)

Comment: @JasonDeVito I agree (and was going to make the same comment), but the idea is not without merit.  If one can show, e.g., left invertible implies determinant nonzero implies right invertible, then this result upgrades the existence of a right inverse into the existence of a two sided inverse.  The result is an incomplete solution, but might be part of a nice solution.

Comment: @Aaron:  I agree that this is a nice result (and worthy of upvote - which I forgot to do earlier and have now remedied).